# Getting current suggestion from `AutoCompleteTextView`

Tags: android, autocomplete

How do you get the current top suggestion in an `AutoCompleteTextView`?  I have it suggesting items, and I have a text change listener registered.  I also have a list on the same screen.  As they type, I want to scroll the list to the current "best" suggestion.  But I can't figure out how to access the current suggestions, or at least the top suggestion.  I guess I'm looking for something like `AutoCompleteTextView.getCurrentSuggestions()`:

```
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String currentText = autoCompleteTextView.getText();
            String bestGuess = autoCompleteTextView.getCurrentSuggestions()[0];
            //                                      ^^^ mewthod doesn't exist
            doSomethingWithGuess(bestGuess);
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // do nothing
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've done what you want to do with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete_1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            Log.d(TAG, "dataset changed");
            Object item = adapter.getItem(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "item.toString "+ item.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

item.toString will print the text that is displayed on the first item.

Note that this will happen even if you aren't showing the pop-up (suggestions) yet. Also, you should check if there are any items that passed the filter criteria (aka the user's input).

To solve the first problem:

```
    int dropDownAnchor = textView.getDropDownAnchor();
    if(dropDownAnchor==0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "drop down id = 0"); // popup is not displayed
        return;
    }
    //do stuff
```

To solve the second problem, use getCount > 0

Comment: Great answer! Much better than my hack below.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I was trying for a few days to figure out how to dynamically change the height of my dropdown based on the number of filtered items and it seemed to filter after the `afterTextChanged` event. The dataSetObserver was exactly the listener that I needed to make it work

Answer (score 1):

AutoCompleteTextView does not scroll down to the best selection, but narrows down the selection as you type. Here is an example of it: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

As I see it from [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) there is no way to get current list of suggestions.

The only way seem to be writing custom version of ArrayAdapter and pass it to AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(..). Here is the [source to ArrayAdapter](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java). You must only change a method in inner class ArrayFilter.performFiltering() so that it exposes FilterResults:

.. add field to inner class ArrayFilter:

```
public ArrayList<T> lastResults;  //add this line
```

.. before end of method performFiltering:

```
  lastResults = (ArrayList<T>) results; // add this line
  return results;
}
```

Using it like this (adapted example from link):

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
CustomArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);

// read suggestions
ArrayList<String> suggestions = adapter.getFilter().lastResult;
```

Comment: i test your code,but in "lastResults = (ArrayList<T>) results" but  we cannot convert a FilterResults type to ArrayList<T>.

Comment: can you tell me how to modify? sdk2.2

Comment: Please look at the answer above - it's better solution than mine ;)