# Autocomplete Text View + Json Server to get Tags Dynamically

Tags: java, android, json, autocompletetextview

I am developing an android application. I have an autocompleteTextView in my layout. I want to populate this textView with the suggestions from my server. There are around 400 keywords on the server and they will increase in near future so i can not parse all the tags at once and then check for suggestions. The autocompleteTextView should work more like as the google search, so that i parse only when the user typed in something and that parsing happens on UI thread.

But i am here not able to trigger that parser since i am not able to get that callback method or may be the event which senses that user has typed something or may be edited some text.

**setOnEditorActionListener**  works only when the user presses the enter button on the soft keyboard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well i got it the method is setTextChangeListener refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954244/getting-current-suggestion-from-autocompletetextview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Filter interface to implement this as well.  Turns out Filter.performFiltering() is called off the UI thread just for this type of purpose.  Here is some code I use to do this:

```
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            return resultValue.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            if( charSequence == null ) return null;
            try {
                // This call hits the server with the name I'm looking for and parses the JSON returned for the first 25 results
                PagedResult results = searchByName( charSequence.toString(), 1, 25, true);
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = results.getResults();
                filterResults.count = results.getResults().size();
                return filterResults;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            if( filterResults != null ) {
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.addAll( (List<MyObject>)filterResults.values );
            }
        }
    };
```

Then using the Filter:

```
    private AutoCompleteTextView beverageName;
    ...

    beverageName = findViewById( R.id.beverageName );
    ListAdapter adapter = ...
    adapter.setFilter(filter);
    beverageName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) interface to do something whenever the user changes the text in an EditText view. Just implement one or more of TextWatcher's methods, I usually use `onTextChanged()`. Hope that helps!