# Choose first suggestion in AutoCompleteTextView using soft keyboard

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, imeoptions

What imeOptions value should I use to choose the first suggestion in the AutoCompleteTextView when "Enter" is pressed on the soft keyboard.

Or is it even in imeOptions power to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954244/getting-current-suggestion-from-autocompletetextview

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is something there but that requires to call a custom method with "Enter" press which is another mystery I cannot find from docs.